# give different widths to different text fields from a form-symfony

Tags: css, forms, symfony-1.4

I have something like this: `<?php echo $form['nome']->renderRow(); ?>`. this gives me the text field, the label and the error message. i need to give different widths to each text field in css. how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `->renderRow();`, you could break it down into component parts, something like this:

```
<?php echo $form['name']->renderLabel() ?>
<?php echo $form['name']->renderError() ?>
<?php echo $form['name'] ?>
```

Then you could wrap those in `div`s with `class` or `id` tags to style accordingly, somethinkg like

```
<div class="nameLabel">
    <?php echo $form['name']->renderLabel() ?>
</div>
```

etc.

Here's a good resource that might help: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers